# Writing new XML element with white space

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to add XML to an existing XML file for filezilla server config. The problem I'm encountering is the element in the original file has a space

```
  <User Name="test">
```

and when I try to use.

```
var element = xdcDocument.CreateElement("User Name");
```

it causes an exception.

I have tried using streamwriter but it just overwrites the entire file.

Any idea how I can get around this problem?

Comment: Read about xml structure to figure out the schema. In your case Name is an attribute of User Element. Your should create an element and then attach attribute to it

Comment: Ok that make sense thanks, how would i then add an attrubute say for example, <User Name="Test">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no white space in your element, it is an `attribute` *Name* with `value` *Test*. Here is how you build up such a structure:

```
var element = xdcDocument.CreateElement("User");
var attribute = xdcDocument.CreateAttribute("Name");
attribute.Value = "Test";        
element.Attributes.Append(attribute);
```